# How to prevent injection when user is supplying an arbitrary SQL identifier?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I need to run `LISTEN channel_name` against a PostgreSQL database using JDBC, where `channel_name` is supplied by a user in a web app.

`channel_name` can be any PostgreSQL identifier.

I don't believe I can use parameterization, and there is no white-list to check against.

How can I allow a user to do so safely?

I considered regexp, but I was wondering if there was anything pre-built, as I don't want to make a mistake.

Current code (doesn't support quoted identifiers or non-ascii chars):

```
public String checkIdentifier(String value) {

    if (!value.matches("(?i)^[a-z_][a-z_0-9\\$]{0,63}$")) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not a valid SQL identifier.");
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Is there no "quote identifier" method available in JDBC? I suppose you could write a tiny PL/pgSQL function that used [`quote_ident`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) and some dynamic SQL but that seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: There's a DatabaseMetaData.getIdentifierQuoteString() function but I think that only returns a "

Comment: Yeah, Craig Ringer's comments on [**How to quote/escape identifiers such as column names with JDBC?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2038169/479863) suggest that there's nothing in JDBC that does the Right Thing.

Comment: Fortunately, it's rather easy to escape identifiers; just replace `"` with `""`, then stick `"`s on both ends.  (Note, this comment only applies if your DB didn't decide to say "screw standards; i'll escape however i want" like MySQL did. :P  Modern PostgreSQL does the right thing, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the note, your current approach is the only sane one if you don't want warts in your database imo.

The built-in Postgres way, if you insist on using it, is to use `quote_ident()` as indicated in the comments. But be wary, because in that case inputs such as `"(?!: .` become valid identifiers. `psql` will handle that well (hopefully), but it can be a pain to type identifiers like that.

Perhaps your ORM has a wrapper for the latter function -- if not, and as highlighted by cHao it's about `"` character handling.

If it's a tablename, you could also cast the thing to `regclass` in order to ensure the identifier exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use a RegExp to parse the channel_name. This way you can verify that the user entry is in a right format and don'y contain any special character that could affect your request.

Comment: Is there something pre-built? It's vital that there are no mistakes.

Comment: I don't know your language but there is a implementation of regular expression in almost every language. Look for the doc of your language.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin: I'm fairly certain he meant "some pre-built way to do what i want", not a pre-built RE api.